# How to visualize the boost graph and perform dijkstra's shortest path?

Tags: c++, boost, graph-theory, dijkstra

I am trying to make a graph with Dijkstra's shortest path. Vertex size can differ later, so I decided to make a bunch of loops to create edges. I am struggling with visualizing the graph in dot file.

I tried
`std::ofstream dot_file("grid.dot"); boost::write_graphviz(dot_file, g);`
But this won't make any new grid file and gives no error.

Also, I am trying to apply Dijkstra's shortest path function. But this line gives me an error.
`dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, vtx_distance, predecessor_map(&p[0]).distance_map(&d[0]));`

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main() {
    struct Vertex {int index;};
    struct Edge {int weight;};
    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS, Vertex, Edge> Graph;
    Graph g;
    typedef graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
    typedef graph_traits < Graph >::edge_descriptor edge_t;
    typedef graph_traits <Graph> Traits;


    vector<int> vertices; 
    int size = 9;
    int size_x = 3;
    int size_y = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        vertices.push_back(i);
    }
    vector<vertex_t> vtx;
    for (int i = 0; i<vertices.size(); i++) {
        vertex_t tmp = add_vertex(g);
        g[tmp].index = vertices.at(i);
        vtx.push_back(tmp); 
    }

 //Add edge in horizontal
    for (int i = 0; i<vertices.size(); i++){
        if (vertices[i] % size_x !=2){
            add_edge(vtx[i], vtx[i + 1], g);
        }
    }
 //Add edge in vertical
    for (int i = 0; i<vertices.size(); i++){
    if (vertices[i] < size - size_y){
        add_edge(vtx[i], vtx[i + size_x], g);
    }
}
//Add edge in diagonal 1
for (int i = 0; i<vertices.size(); i++){
    if (vertices[i] % size_x != 2 && vertices[i] < size - size_y){
        add_edge(vtx[i], vtx[i + 1 + size_x], g);
    }
}
//Add edge in diagonal 2
for (int i = 0; i<vertices.size(); i++){
    if (vertices[i] % size_x != 0 && vertices[i] < size - size_y){
        add_edge(vtx[i], vtx[i - 1 + size_x], g);
    }
}

vector<int> d(num_vertices(g));
vector<vertex_t> p(num_vertices(g));
vertex_t vtx_distance = vertex(0, g);

dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, vtx_distance, predecessor_map(&p[0]).distance_map(&d[0]));

std::cout << "distances and parents:" << std::endl;


//    std::ofstream file("grid.dot");
    std::ofstream dot_file("grid.dot");
    boost::write_graphviz(dot_file, g);
}
```

Image of the graph I want to make (without dijkstra).
[image]

Comment: You seem to have several problems.  Pick one and focus your question on that.

Comment: [Please post your errors as text, not as an image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3282436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step I reviewed your graph creation code. It seems unnecessarily complicated.

### Getting On The Grid

Let's simplify, based on the observation that `vecS` vertex container selector implies contiguous integral vertex descriptors, starting at 0:

```
Graph make_grid(size_t size_x, int size_y)
{
    Graph g(size_x * size_y);

    using boost::make_iterator_range;
    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
        g[v].index = v;

    auto col     = [=](vertex_t v) { return v % size_x; };
    auto row     = [=](vertex_t v) { return v / size_x; };
    auto lastcol = [=](vertex_t v) { return col(v) == size_x - 1; };
    auto lastrow = [=](vertex_t v) { return row(v) == size_y - 1; };

    // Add edges
    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
        if (not lastrow(v))
            add_edge(v, v + size_x, g); // vertical
        if (not lastcol(v))
            add_edge(v, v + 1, g); // horizontal
        if (not(lastrow(v) || lastcol(v)))
            add_edge(v, v + 1 + size_x, g); // down-right
        if (not(lastrow(v) || 0 == col(v)))
            add_edge(v, v - 1 + size_x, g); // down-left
    }
    return g;
}
```

That's all. It makes the graph.

### Publish It!

Now you want to print it. Let's do that:

```
std::ofstream dot_file("grid.dot");
boost::write_graphviz(dot_file, g);
if (auto code = system("neato -T png grid.dot -o grid.png"))
    return code;
```

Results in

[image]

### The Editor Wants A Word

You can spice things up with graphviz node/edge attributes. Let's add colors and save those as well:

```
struct Edge { int weight; std::string color; };

...
// generating different color edges per direction
if (not lastrow(v))
    add_edge(v, v + size_x, Edge{weightgen(), "red"}, g); // vertical
if (not lastcol(v))
    add_edge(v, v + 1, Edge{weightgen(), "green"}, g); // horizontal
if (not(lastrow(v) || lastcol(v)))
    add_edge(v, v + 1 + size_x, Edge{weightgen(), "blue"}, g); // down-right
if (not(lastrow(v) || 0 == col(v)))
    add_edge(v, v - 1 + size_x, Edge{weightgen(), "brown"}, g); // down-left
```

Let's extract saving to a function as well:

```
void save(std::string const name, Graph const& g) {
    std::ofstream dot_file(name + ".dot");

    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("node_id",   get(boost::vertex_index, g));
    dp.property("label",     get(&Edge::weight,       g));
    dp.property("color",     get(&Edge::color,        g));
    dp.property("fontcolor", get(&Edge::color,        g));
    boost::write_graphviz_dp(dot_file, g, dp);

    std::ostringstream cmd;
    cmd << "neato -T png " //
        << std::quoted(name + ".dot", '\'') << " -o "
        << std::quoted(name + ".png", '\'');

    if (auto code = system(cmd.str().c_str())) {
        if (code == -1)
            ::perror(name.data());
        ::exit(code);
    }
}
```

Now the result is: [image]

### Enter Dijkstra

you have compilation failures. They're due to the use of raw pointers (`&d[0]` e.g.) as property maps. This has been deprecated and removed long time ago. So, make explicit property maps instead, e.g.:

```
auto vidx = get(boost::vertex_index, g);
auto wmap = get(&Edge::weight, g);
auto dmap = boost::make_iterator_property_map(d.begin(), vidx);
auto pmap = boost::make_iterator_property_map(p.begin(), vidx);

dijkstra_shortest_paths(         //
    g,                           //
    V{0},                        //
    boost::predecessor_map(pmap) //
        .distance_map(dmap)      //
        .weight_map(wmap));
```

That compiles. I'm not too sure what exactly about the output you'd like to have visualized. Perhaps we can grey out any edges that are not in the path?

```
for (auto e : make_iterator_range(edges(g))) {
    auto v = source(e,g), u = target(e,g);
    if (p.at(u) != v)
        g[e].color = "lightgrey";
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

### FULL LISTING

**["Live" On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e364f77ceadbe4ec)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct Vertex { int index;  };
struct Edge { int weight; std::string color; };

using Graph    = boost::adjacency_list< //
    boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, Vertex, Edge>;

using Traits   = boost::graph_traits<Graph>;
using V = Traits::vertex_descriptor;
using E = Traits::edge_descriptor;

Graph make_grid(size_t size_x, size_t size_y)
{
    Graph g(size_x * size_y);

    using boost::make_iterator_range;
    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
        g[v].index = v;

    auto col     = [=](V v) { return v % size_x; };
    auto row     = [=](V v) { return v / size_x; };
    auto lastcol = [=](V v) { return col(v) == size_x - 1; };
    auto lastrow = [=](V v) { return row(v) == size_y - 1; };

    // Add edges
    auto weightgen = [] { return rand() % 5 + 1; };
    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
        if (not lastrow(v))
            add_edge(v, v + size_x, Edge{weightgen(), "red"}, g); // vertical
        if (not lastcol(v))
            add_edge(v, v + 1, Edge{weightgen(), "green"}, g); // horizontal
        if (not(lastrow(v) || lastcol(v)))
            add_edge(v, v + 1 + size_x, Edge{weightgen(), "blue"}, g); // down-right
        if (not(lastrow(v) || 0 == col(v)))
            add_edge(v, v - 1 + size_x, Edge{weightgen(), "brown"}, g); // down-left
    }
    return g;
}

void save(std::string const name, Graph& g) {
    std::ofstream dot_file(name + ".dot");

    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("node_id",   get(boost::vertex_index, g));
    dp.property("label",     get(&Edge::weight,       g));
    dp.property("color",     get(&Edge::color,        g));
    dp.property("fontcolor", get(&Edge::color,        g));

    boost::write_graphviz_dp(dot_file, g, dp);

    std::ostringstream cmd;
    cmd << "neato -T png " //
        << std::quoted(name + ".dot", '\'') << " -o "
        << std::quoted(name + ".png", '\'');

    if (auto code = system(cmd.str().c_str())) {
        if (code == -1)
            ::perror(name.data());
        ::exit(code);
    }
}

int main() {
    Graph g = make_grid(3, 3);

    save("grid", g);

    std::vector<int> d(num_vertices(g));
    std::vector<V>   p(num_vertices(g));

    auto vidx = get(boost::vertex_index, g);
    auto wmap = get(&Edge::weight, g);
    auto dmap = boost::make_iterator_property_map(d.begin(), vidx);
    auto pmap = boost::make_iterator_property_map(p.begin(), vidx);

    dijkstra_shortest_paths(         //
        g,                           //
        V{0},                        //
        boost::predecessor_map(pmap) //
            .distance_map(dmap)      //
            .weight_map(wmap));

    for (auto e : make_iterator_range(edges(g))) {
        auto v = source(e,g), u = target(e,g);
        if (p.at(u) != v)
            g[e].color = "lightgrey";
    }

    save("path", g);
}
```

Comment: Very impressive and comprehensive answer.